# Unable to open executable jar file

Tags: java, jar

These are precisely the steps that took to create executable jar file so that i can run my swing program by double clicking but it gives me an error saying "Invalid or corrupt jar file"
Also trying to execute it through command prompt gives me the same error

```
Step 1:create a .java file which contains my swing code
Step 2:compile the .java file to .class file
Step 3:create jar file using the command jar cf name.jar classname.class
Step 4:open jar file using winrar archiever and modify manifest file by adding Main-class:classname
Step 5:try to execute the jar file
```

BUT the above steps dont work and i dont understand why?

I tried another thing too

```
Step 1:create a .java file which contains my swing code
Step 2:compile the .java file to .class file
Step 3:create jar file using the command jar cf name classname.class
Step 4:open jar file using winrar archiever and modify manifest file by adding Main-class:classname
Step 5:try to execute the jar file.In this case i can open my file through command prompt but not by double clicking. I tried to select javaw option through Open with option but it doesn't give any ouput(not even error)
```

Comment: Try to run it with `java -jar file.jar`.

Comment: i tried that but it gives the same error "Invalid or corrupt jar file"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
java -cp name.jar Classname
```

and check for errors at the command prompt.

If your program requires some external libraries, you can mention them inside the manifest file.

```
Class-Path: lib/file1.jar lib/file2.jar
```

where `lib` is in the same directory where the jar file is.

Comment: `-cp` means you are in including the jar in your classpath.

Comment: i am sorry but i didn't understand what it means. Can you please explain again?

Comment: By default, java will look only into the classpath which is current directory and its default libraries. But `-cp name.jar` forces jvm to consider `name.jar` as well into classpath, So your Class inside jar was visible to JVM which may be not earlier